# Is "as you need" different from "as you need to" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

To utilize things as(when) you need to, but never be captivated by things.(self-made, a translation from ancient text in Chinese)

I think "as you need" and "as you need to" is different in this context. Because "as you need" may be followed by noun, but "as you need to" is to be followed by verb. Which one do you think is more appropriate in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

If my deduction is correct, the better sentence (clause) will be like this:

> To utilize things when you need to, but never be captivated by them.

Because the complete version of the sentence (again, clause) you wrote is this:

> To utilize things when you need to utilize them, but never be captivated by them.

or:

> To utilize things when you need to do so, but never be captivated by them.

There is no `to` needed if you write it like this:

> Things utilized as you need.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is different as one needs water, later one needs to pee. The word "to" requires action of some sort.

Comment: It's not *to* that requires action, it's *needs to*.

Comment: Okay, I agree. Cause and effect. One statement calls for action.